# Search in SharePoint 2013 by CreatedDate is not working

Tags: search, date-time

Search in SharePoint 2013 by Created Date is not working in advance search web part.

I have created the site column in document library "ReviewExpirationDate" add data in it . after that full crawl and then map its Crawled property and managed property.Again run full crawl. Other column search working fine but date column not show me any data.

Comment: Can you please add more details? Like the query you are executing

Comment: I have created the site column in document library "ReviewExpirationDate" add data in it . after that full crawl and then map its Crawled property and managed property.Again run full crawl. Other column search working fine but date column not show me any data.